# Proof that $\forall x \in \Omega: \neg a(x) \Leftrightarrow \neg(\exists x \in \Omega: a(x))$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

> Let $\Omega$ be a set and $a(x)$ any statement about $x \in \Omega$.
>   Proof that
>
> $$\forall x \in \Omega: \neg a(x) \Leftrightarrow \neg(\exists x \in
> \Omega: a(x))$$

I think there is no way in proving this without giving an example or describing, right?

I tried:

What the left side is saying is that for all x in the set omega, we have that "not a(x)".

This is equivalent to: There does not exist an x in the set omega so that we have a(x).

That's what the task is saying in maths language.

So left side: No matter (=all) what x we choose, we will always get "not a(x)".

Right side: There doesn't exist an x to get a(x).

This is really the same but how can you prove this? This is very frustrating task because it makes sense but you cannot prove it / prove it easily : /

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. Assume first the LHS is true and the parenthesised part of the RHS as well (to go for a contradiction), and you easily deduce a contradiction. Also assuming the RHS and taking an arbitrary $x\in\Omega$, the assumption $a(x)$ easily leads to a contradiction, so it must be false.Since $x$ was arbitrary, you get that conclusion for all $x$.

Comment: This is the quantified version of DeMorgan's Law.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the negation of \forall quantifier? If not, you can show the \Leftarrow quite easily, for \Rightarrow just assume \exists x \in
\Omega: a(x) to be true and arrive at a contradiction. Then by the CTR rule, you derive FALSE which means your assumption must be true.

Comment: Can anyone of you write a proof for this please? I still don't know how to proof a strange task like that, if there is one in the exam I write soon. I really understand what it's saying and why it's true but the proof... How?

Comment: You can prove $\neg ( p \wedge q) \leftrightarrow \neg p \vee \neg q$ using a truth table.  Since, by definition, $\forall {x \in \Omega}: a(x) \leftrightarrow a(x_1) \wedge a(x_2) \wedge \dots a(x_n)$ and $\exists {x \in \Omega}: a(x) \leftrightarrow a(x_1) \vee a(x_2) \vee \dots a(x_n)$ where the $x_i$ are precisely the elements of $\Omega$, the formula follows.

Comment: "$a$ is always false if and only if $a$ is never true".  This is a trivial result, it is meaningless to ask for a proof unless you specify a logic.